# How to bind attributes in an Angular directive using TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

Using AngularJS 1.5 and TypeScript I am writing a directive and want to define an attribute in my view that gets passed into the directive and then used to output to a template. I have tried to follow some examples such as [this one](https://hstefanski.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/converting-an-angular-app-to-typescript-part-2/), but my directive template isn't binding to the attribute.

HTML from page:

```html
<my-directive name="John"></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
module myApp.directives {
    "use strict";

    export class myDirective {
      static directiveId = 'myDirective';
      scope = {};
      bindToController = {
        name: '='
      };
      restrict = 'EA';
      controller = controllers.NameController.ControllerId;
      controllerAs = 'vm';
      template = '<h1>Name: {{ vm.name }}</h1>';

      static $inject = [];
      constructor() { }

      static instance() {
        return new myDirective();
      }
    }
    angular.module("myApp").directive(myDirective.directiveId, myDirective.instance);
}
```

Controller (not really sure I need anything in the constructor?):

```
module myApp.controllers {
    "use strict";

    export class NameController {
        static ControllerId = "NameController";
        name: string;

        constructor(name: string){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    angular.module("myApp").controller(NameController.ControllerId, NameController);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bindToController should accept a string litteral and not a bound property, i.e.

`bindToController = {
     name: '@'
   };`

the `=` will try to evaluate a property called `John` in your syntax, which does not exist.

Also, your constructor does not need any parameter, and for what I see can be totally removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this helps, neither how angular is merging instance of NameController and $scope together, but I can imaging that name property of NameController instance is shadowing $scope.name.

Would you try removing:

```
name: string;

constructor(name: string) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

?

Comment: When I remove that, my view changes from displaying "Name: {{ vm.name }}"(braces are visible) to "Name: "(no braces but also no data).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the attribute you need should be defined on the directive scope, seeing as you are already using isolated scope. Doesn't look like you are using `bindToController` anywhere.

Instead of this:

```
scope = {};
bindToController = {
  name: '='
};
```

Try with this (older syntax):

```
scope = {
  name: '='
};
```

Also, the parameterized constructor in controller won't run since you aren't `new`-ing up the class (in the line below, from your second code snippet)

```
angular.module("myApp").controller(NameController.ControllerId, NameController);
```